# Why API doesn't update the mongodb registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I want to update a mongo collection, the result is {"n": 1, "nModified": 0, "ok": 1}

I understand you found the collection but I can't update, is that so?

We are using mongoose ^ 5.7.4 and the updateOne () function

Anyone know what can happen?

**Log :**

```
18:36:40 -METHOD PUT -URL http://localhost:4200/ -O-URL /api/movement-of-article?id=5e1499c11b5dfc272c378533
         -PARAMS {}
         -BODY {"basePrice":40,"costPrice":48.4,"unitPrice":130,"markupPercentage":168.595,"markupPrice":81.6,"transactionDiscountAmount":0,"salePrice":130,"roundingAmount":0,"amount":1,"quantityForStock":0,"status":"Listo","printed":0,"modifyStock":true,"_id":"5e1499c11b5dfc272c378533","otherFields":[],"taxes":[{"percentage":21,"taxBase":107.44,"taxAmount":22.562,"tax":{"code":"5","percentage":21,"amount":0,"lastNumber":0,"_id":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f63","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2018-08-24T02:16:58.000Z","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","name":"IVA","__v":0,"classification":"Impuesto","taxBase":"Gravado","type":"Nacional","updateDate":"2019-06-11T06:05:01.000Z","updateUser":"5b85ea5ca529c26ac94f0f9b"}},{"percentage":0,"taxBase":130,"taxAmount":0,"tax":{"code":"0","percentage":0,"amount":0,"lastNumber":0,"_id":"5e148257f08f80197ce55d31","name":"0","taxBase":"Gravado","classification":"Impuesto","type":"Nacional","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","creationDate":"2020-01-07T13:06:31.000Z","operationType":"C","__v":0}}],"code":"0000000001","codeSAT":"","description":"Gaseosa grande","observation":"","make":null,"category":{"order":1,"picture":"default.jpg","visibleInvoice":false,"visibleOnSale":false,"visibleOnPurchase":true,"ecommerceEnabled":false,"_id":"5b87259ed700ce47ad019d14","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2018-08-29T03:57:46.000Z","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","description":"Bebidas sin alcohol","__v":0,"updateDate":"2020-01-03T18:03:21.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b"},"article":{"type":"Final","containsVariants":false,"quantityPerMeasure":1,"notes":["SIN AZUCAR","LIGTH","COCA CERO"],"basePrice":40,"costPrice":48.4,"markupPercentage":168.6,"markupPrice":81.6,"salePrice":130,"posKitchen":true,"allowPurchase":true,"allowSale":true,"allowSaleWithoutStock":true,"allowMeasure":false,"ecommerceEnabled":false,"favourite":false,"isWeigth":false,"picture":"default.jpg","providers":null,"_id":"5b87524dd700ce47ad019f03","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2018-08-29T03:57:46.000Z","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","printIn":"Mostrador","barcode":"","category":"5b87259ed700ce47ad019d14","deposit":null,"make":null,"taxes":[{"percentage":21,"taxBase":40,"taxAmount":8.4,"_id":"5d3b6389e7bb71593f98f65a","tax":{"code":"5","percentage":21,"amount":0,"lastNumber":0,"_id":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f63","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2018-08-24T02:16:58.000Z","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","name":"IVA","__v":0,"classification":"Impuesto","taxBase":"Gravado","type":"Nacional","updateDate":"2019-06-11T06:05:01.000Z","updateUser":"5b85ea5ca529c26ac94f0f9b"}},{"percentage":0,"taxBase":0,"taxAmount":0,"_id":"5e148268f08f80197ce55d34","tax":{"code":"0","percentage":0,"amount":0,"lastNumber":0,"_id":"5e148257f08f80197ce55d31","name":"0","taxBase":"Gravado","classification":"Impuesto","type":"Nacional","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","creationDate":"2020-01-07T13:06:31.000Z","operationType":"C","__v":0}}],"observation":"","posDescription":"Gaseosa Grande","description":"Gaseosa grande","code":"0000000001","__v":0,"updateDate":"2020-01-07T13:06:48.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","location":null,"codeSAT":"","currency":null,"unitOfMeasurement":null,"otherFields":[],"children":[],"deposits":[],"locations":[],"classification":null},"transaction":{"origin":0,"letter":"","number":2,"basePrice":263.27,"exempt":0,"discountAmount":0,"discountPercent":0,"totalPrice":161.25,"roundingAmount":0,"diners":0,"balance":0,"_id":"5e149131f08f80197ce55d78","startDate":"2020-01-07T14:09:50.000Z","VATPeriod":"202001","state":"Abierto","madein":"mostrador","quotation":1,"type":{"modifyStock":true,"requestArticles":true,"modifyArticle":false,"entryAmount":"Venta con IVA","requestTaxes":true,"defectOrders":true,"allowAPP":false,"allowEdit":true,"allowDelete":false,"allowZero":false,"electronics":false,"fixedOrigin":0,"tax":false,"cashBoxImpact":true,"cashOpening":false,"cashClosing":false,"requestPaymentMethods":true,"requestCurrency":false,"requestTransport":false,"showPrices":true,"automaticNumbering":true,"automaticCreation":true,"printable":true,"isPreprinted":false,"showPriceType":"Precio Final","showDescriptionType":"Descripción","printDescriptionType":"Descripción","printSign":false,"posKitchen":true,"readLayout":false,"updatePrice":false,"updateArticle":false,"_id":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f74","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2018-08-24T02:16:58.000Z","creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","defectPrinter":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f6a","movement":"Entrada","currentAccount":"Si","name":"Ticket","transactionMovement":"Venta","__v":0,"codes":[{"letter":"A","code":0},{"letter":"B","code":0},{"letter":"C","code":0}],"fixedLetter":"","labelPrint":"","stockMovement":"Salida","updateDate":"2020-01-03T00:34:57.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","requestEmployee":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f55","fastPayment":null,"abbreviation":"","fiscalCode":"","requestCompany":null,"defectUseOfCFDI":null},"cashBox":"5dfd729d5ffe0f55e8a1bdcd","branchOrigin":{"default":false,"_id":"5d19abe23cdc4113c8ff7b6e","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2019-07-01T06:39:08.000Z","creationUser":"5b85ea5ca529c26ac94f0f9b","name":"Principal","number":1,"__v":0,"image":"default.jpg","updateDate":"2020-01-03T15:25:38.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b"},"branchDestination":{"default":false,"_id":"5d19abe23cdc4113c8ff7b6e","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2019-07-01T06:39:08.000Z","creationUser":"5b85ea5ca529c26ac94f0f9b","name":"Principal","number":1,"__v":0,"image":"default.jpg","updateDate":"2020-01-03T15:25:38.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b"},"depositOrigin":{"default":false,"_id":"5d19abe93cdc4113c8ff7b70","operationType":"C","creationUser":"5b85ea5ca529c26ac94f0f9b","branch":"5d19abe23cdc4113c8ff7b6e","capacity":null,"name":"1","__v":0},"depositDestination":{"default":false,"_id":"5d19abe93cdc4113c8ff7b70","operationType":"C","creationUser":"5b85ea5ca529c26ac94f0f9b","branch":"5d19abe23cdc4113c8ff7b6e","capacity":null,"name":"1","__v":0},"creationUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","creationDate":"2020-01-07T14:09:53.000Z","operationType":"U","__v":0,"taxes":[{"percentage":21,"taxBase":133.27,"taxAmount":27.99,"_id":"5e1499c31b5dfc272c378546","tax":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f63"},{"percentage":0,"taxBase":130,"taxAmount":0,"_id":"5e1499c31b5dfc272c378545","tax":"5e148257f08f80197ce55d31"}],"updateDate":"2020-01-07T21:36:40.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","employeeClosing":"5b907b5a06b4ba59772d231d","employeeOpening":"5b907b5a06b4ba59772d231d"},"quantityMeasure":1,"stockMovement":"Salida","creationUser":{"tokenExpiration":1440,"_id":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","password":"$2a$12$KDSkhk4PiZaCnSKVEjyx9eWTt3TOTMyGlIR2NDYshFH444mPi8dPG","operationType":"U","creationDate":"2018-08-24T02:16:58.000Z","employee":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5a","state":"Habilitado","name":"admin","__v":0,"updateDate":"2020-01-02T19:18:47.000Z","updateUser":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","email":"admin@barcino","company":null,"origin":null,"printers":[],"shortcuts":[{"_id":"5e07ca4c51ab9a20d0870bcb","name":"Jackson","url":"pos/delivery?states=Preparando,Armando,Entregado"},{"_id":"5e0e26c542aaf51c147db33e","name":"Armado de pedidos","url":"pos/armado-de-pedidos"},{"_id":"5e0e42179321272b14cd87c6","name":"Retiro de pedidos","url":"pos/retiro-de-pedidos"}]},"creationDate":"2020-01-07T14:46:25.000Z","operationType":"U","__v":0,"updateDate":"2020-01-07T18:36:40-03:00","updateUser":{"tokenExpiration":1440,"_id":"5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b","shortcuts":[],"printers":[]}}
         -D barcino
         -USER admin(5b85e796a529c26ac94f0f5b)
         -CLIENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
         -STATUS 500
         -MSN {"n":1,"nModified":0,"ok":1}
```

Code UPDATE

```
    async function update(req, res, next, movementOfArticleId, movementOfArticle) {

 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  initConnectionDB(req.session.database);

  var user = new User();
  user._id = req.session.user;
  movementOfArticle.updateUser = user;
  movementOfArticle.updateDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
  movementOfArticle.operationType = 'U';
  await MovementOfArticle.updateOne({ _id: movementOfArticleId }, movementOfArticle, async (err, result) => {
   if (err) {
    reject(err);
   } else {
    if (result && result.ok == 1 && result.nModified == 1) {
     await get(movementOfArticleId).then(
      movementOfArticle => {
       resolve(movementOfArticle);
      }
     ).catch(
      err => {
       reject(err);
      }
     );
    } else {
     reject(result);
    }
   }
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with proper words, I tried my best to edit it but it still has some grammatical issues.

Comment: Ok if I understand it correct you wanted to update you documents in collection but not able to as result says `nModified :0`, So first try running a `.find()` query with the filters and check whether proper documents being returned or not & Why don't you post your documents & ask for a required o/p if your query is not able to update your documents even after trying directly on DB..

Comment: When I send the first update it returns {"n": 1, "nModified": 0, "ok": 1} but when I do it a second time with the same JSON it updates correctly. Could it be that if the JSON changes the location values ​​it cannot update?

Comment: what do you mean by `if the JSON changes the location values ​​it cannot update` ? updates should not fail intermittently with same JSON, usually if there is a field `abc : true`, first request is to make it `false` will update but second request with same JSON will not update anything(but DB transaction is success) but in your case how come first req is failing & second is working did you print JSON's & checked properly ?

Comment: Print the JSON and they are the same in the first update (fails) and in the second (successful)

Comment: Can you edit question with code that updates mongoDB